# Mask sensitive data in production

Tags: security, data-protection-and-privacy

Is anyone aware of how to mask sensitive data within the GUI?  I have seen some mention in Sandboxes,but wanted to see if anyone was doing this in production?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use case for masking?

Comment: @JohnWhelan Ideally, have some users that are unable to see certain sensitive data, as it doesn't apply to their job within the system.  I know that is a stretch, just seeing if it is possible.

Comment: You should be able to do this with field level security (FLS):  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_fls.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to mask an existing field or a new one?, if you are trying to create a new field you can use the "Text(Encrypted)" Data Type

[image: DataType Screen]

Answer (score 0):

If it's only a few fields with a well-known audience (who should see masked values), create a formula field with a mask and hide the "source" field the by removing it from the page via a page layout. Assign the page layout with a hidden field via a profile / permission set to the aforementioned audience. This would only work if the user can't see the "source" field via any other means.